# Login Issues on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Whenever I put in my password, it cuts to a few lines of code then returns to the login. I've tried edm and lightdm, nothing works.

Comment: it would be good if you could tell what those lines say?

Comment: They are there for half a second

Comment: ok I'll write an answer check if it will work for you

Comment: It says:Starting configure network device security          Starting configure network device                          Starting Virtualbox kernel modules Stopping cold ping devices   Stopping log initial device creation                     Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices  Starting configure network device security               Starting virtual network devices                         Stopping enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices  Stopping configure virtual network devices                ........done...         sound disabled : edit/etc/default/saned

Comment: Every capital starting is a new line

Answer (score 0):

Firstly when you're at the login screen open console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start
```

if it doesn't work try this:

From your tty remove the .Xauthority file and also need to remove the .xsession-errors files.

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
sudo rm .xsession-errors*
```

Check the home directory:

```
ls -l /home
```

you may have to give ownership back to your account using chown

```
sudo chown -R username:group /home/username
```

Answer (score 0):

It will log out you automatically if you write a bash_profile and it ends with `exit 0`. I recommended you  that restart your system and press F10 at boot. Enter the recovery mode in grup screen and select root (drop to root shell prompt). Then open your bash_profile with `nano ~/.bash_profile` and remove line `exit 0`.

Comment: Got to recovery, but came up blank with no script or words.